# Hermitian forms over quaternion algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, quadratic-forms, division-algebras, involutions

*Notations*: Let $Q=(a,b)$ be a quaternion algebra over a field of characteristic $\neq 2$, i.e. $i^2=a, j^2=b, k=ij, ij=-ji$. Consider $K=k(t)(\alpha)$, where $\alpha=\sqrt{at^2+b}$. Let $\sigma=Int(i)\circ\tau$, here we define $Int(i)(x)=ixi^{-1}$ and $\tau$ is canonical involution given by $\tau(x_1+x_2i+x_3j+x_4k)=x_1-x_2i-x_3j-x_4k$. Thus $\sigma$ will be an orthogonal involution on $Q$.

Now $Q$ splits over $K$ and canonical involution on $M_2(K)$ is defined by $*:\begin{pmatrix}x & y \\z & w\end{pmatrix}\to \begin{pmatrix} w & -y \\-z & x \end{pmatrix} $. Splitting of $(Q,\tau)$ can be given by $f:(Q,\tau)\to M_2(K)$ by mapping $i\to \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\0 & -\alpha \end{pmatrix}, j\to \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. In this case $f$ is isomorphism of algebra with involution i.e.  $*\circ f=f\circ\tau$.

I have following questions:

1.$(Q,\sigma)$ also splits on $(M_2(K))$ what will be an isomorphism preserving involutions?

2.Given a skew-hermitian form say $<i,j,k>$ with respect to $\tau$ how we can explicitly calculate corresponding hermitian form wrt $\sigma$.

I first thought that multiplication by image of $i$ to the canonical involution on $M_2(K)$ will give answer to Question 1 above, but it does not work out. Can somebody give reference/hint for doing such explicit calculations?

Comment: Do you mean $i^2=at^2+b$ and $j\mapsto\left(\begin{matrix}0&b\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)$ ? Otherwise, your "splitting" of $(Q,\tau)$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: Concerning the second question: is a $Q$-module with a "given skew-hermitian" $\tau$-form arbitrary?

Comment: @SashaAnan'in, yes $j$ should map to the element you described. Actually over $K$, the norm form associated to $Q$ is same as norm form associated to $(at^2+b,ab(at^2+b))$ so indeed we can take $i^2=at^2+b$. $Q$-module is arbitrary. But for explicit computation, we can take 3 dimensional right $Q$-module.